# PHPSpreadsheet read styles from text in a cell

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm having the following cell data:

bla bla bla **abcd** *efgh* ***ijkl***

Notice, `abcd` is bold, `efgh` is italic, and `ijkl` is both bold and italic at the same time.

I would like to read the data for this entire cell, and save it in the database, so that I can then present it to the end-user as is (meaning with those styles).
I've searched the docs, and I only could adapt this code:

```
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../intrebari.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($path);
$bold = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->getFont()->getBold();
```

But the problem with it is that this works only if the entire cell text is bold, and in my case, only part of it is bold.

Anyone knows how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cells with multiple formatting use  `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText` (see: [Add rich text to a cell](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#add-rich-text-to-a-cell) in the documentation).

To get the information needed you can use something like this:

```
$cellValue = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A3')->getValue();
        
if ($cellValue instanceof \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText) {
       foreach ($cellValue->getRichTextElements() as $richTextElement) {
                var_dump($richTextElement->getText());
                var_dump($richTextElement->getFont()->getBold());
       }
}
```